# Convert line coordinate data to list of tuples for plotting

Tags: python, mathematical-morphology

I am trying to plot a set of shape outlines. I have a dataframe where each shape is a row and the coordinates are in columns. I have 10 groups of (x,y) coordinates and I want to be able to plot each of the shapes on the same graph.

I was able to plot a single shape if I turned it into a list of tuples, but I want to be able to automate the process instead of doing it by hand.

Is there a way to do this or a better way of plotting the shape outlines?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated some fake data to show a startegy but you can first read this table into pandas using `pd.read_csv()`. I only put 4 coordinates (X1-4, Y1-4) for simplicity.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read in the tabular data
# df = pd.read_csv(filename) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Species': ['B6','B6','B6','FVBN'],
                   'Age': ['P28', 'P28', 'P28', 'P28'],
                   'Brain': [1,2,3,4],
                  'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                  'X1': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'Y1': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'X2': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'Y2': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'X3': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'Y3': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'X4': np.random.randint(0,10,4),
                  'Y4': np.random.randint(0,10,4)}
                  )
```

Then you can iterate the rows of your dataframe `df`, collect (x,y) (notice that I repeated X1,Y1 at the end so the polygon is closed) and plot on an existing axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    x = row[['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X1']]
    y = row[['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'Y1']]
    ax.plot(x,y)
fig.show()
```